# Simplest way to get mobile device tokens

Tags: c#, xamarin, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I just want to know what's the easiest way to get the device token (iOS, Android, UWP) on my Xamarin project.

The point is, I don't want to send push notifications! It is just the token. My online research was not very successful.

Best regards

Comment: If you aren't using the push device token for push notifications, then I would question your purpose for this code. If its the case you need to identify a device for a user you could generate your own token to achieve this or make use of a unique device id.

Comment: @Simon I just need to generate this token on my Xamarin project to save it in my database. The push service is part of a another service, stored in a separate C# project.
I know how to implement the push service on a basic C# project, but using Xamarin is much more complicated.